# Uso de expresiones lambda en Java

Tags: java, lambda

Estoy practicando expresiones Lambda y tengo lo siguiente.
Tengo una clase persona:

```
 private static class Persona {
    public int a;
    public String b;


    public Persona(int a,String b){
        this.a=a;
        this.b=b;
    }

    public String toString(){
    return a+","+b;
    }

    public int getA(){
    return a;
    }
   }
```

Tengo un ArrayList con los siguientes datos:

```
 ArrayList<Persona> array=new ArrayList<Persona>();
        array.add(new Persona(1,"a"));
        array.add(new Persona(2,"b"));
        array.add(new Persona(3,"c"));
```

apliqué el siguiente map:

```
  array.stream().map(p->p=new Persona(p.a+1,p.b)).forEach(System.out::println);
```

El resultado que obtengo es correcto y es:

> 2,a
>
> 3,b
>
> 4,c

Mi pregunta es si hay alguna manera de sumar 1 al atributo a de cada persona que se encuentra en el ArrayList sin crear un nuevo Objeto y que se imprima de la misma forma.

Antes intenté `array.stream().map(p->p.a+1).forEach(System.out::println);` pero sólo se imprime:

> 2
>
> 3
>
> 4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo con `forEach`:

```
//necesitarás crear el setter apropiado
array.stream().forEach(p -> p.setA(p.getA() + 1));
```

Considera que [`Stream#map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) sirve para generar un nuevo stream basado en la transformación aplicada a cada elemento del stream actual, no para modificar los valores actuales del stream.

Answer (score 0):

Hola puedes probar con el metodo replaceAll el cual recibe un UnaryOperator :

```
array.replaceAll( x -> new Persona(x.a+1, x.b) );
array.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Espero te sirva

Saludos.